# Are these two prepositional phrases disjuncts or something else?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adjuncts

Are these two prepositional phrases disjuncts or something else? I’ve looked through Biber and Huddleston, and the two examples don’t seem to fit into any of their categories of disjuncts. Thanks in advance!

**Given the issue's complexity**, a brief summary is difficult.

**Considering his size**, he was speedy.

UPDATE: I thought I would provide some background on my question since someone asked which books I was using. I’ve been looking at these three books:

Huddleston - Cambridge Grammar of English Language (2002),
Biber - Grammar of Spoken and Written English (1999),
Quirk - Comprehensive Grammar English (1985)

I am focused on prepositional phrases. I can’t find the answers to any of my remaining questions about prepositional phrases in any of their books. The authors frequently use the PPs I’m confused about in their own writing, but they don’t address them directly in their books. Huddleston points out a few types of adjuncts that can’t be directly questioned using When? Where? How? and Why? Having said that, it would seem that the ones he doesn’t point out as such should be “questionable.” All of the disjuncts and conjunct examples these sources present are simple to understand. And it makes sense that if the prepositional phrase is not a disjunct or conjunct, then it must be an adjunct. However, I should be able to see how a prepositional phrase adjunct fits into at least one of their models. Adjuncts don’t modify entire sentences, do they? I thought only disjuncts did that. So, there’s a bit more background on my questions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you give a date/title  for the Biber and Huddleston, please?

Comment: Hi Josh. Welcome to EL&U :-)  It's always good to wait a day or two before selecting an answer. You may get several more answers with other ideas or different advice. But people may not bother to write you another answer if you've already selected one! (you can unselect it for the time being by clicking on the green tick - you can put it back again later on the same answer if you want to) Keep asking good questions!

Comment: I’ll do that. I think you are correct with the first one at least. It seems to answer the question Why? The second one doesn’t seem to answer any of the main “adjunct questions.”

Comment: Josh, Which Huddleston book have you been looking at? and which Biber book? It's difficult to give you a really good answer without this info! The definitions of *adjunct* and so forth have changed a lot over the years, so it's difficult to give you a good explanation of why these are adjunct if we don't know which versions of these words you're referring to. :)

Comment: I’ve been looking at these three books:
Huddleston - Cambridge Grammar of English Language (2002),
Biber - Grammar of Spoken and Written English (1999),
Quirk - Comprehensive Grammar English (1985).

Comment: Huddleston & Pullum (H&P) don't recognise the term *adverbial* and don't recognise *subjuncts, conjuncts* or *disjuncts*. They would argue that all of these terms are a result of confusing the syntactic functions, the type of word/phrase and the semantics. One of the main principles of H&P is to keep these three things entirely separate. Nowadays, not many people, if anyone, really refers to subjuncts, conjuncts or disjuncts (with the meanings laid out in Quirk et al). For H&P the definition of *Adjunct* is very simple ...

Comment: ... It is a Modifier of the clause or verb phrase.

Comment: It seems some of my confusion is over whether they modify the “clause or the verb phrase.” Do the PPs above modify the clause or the verb phrase, or in those cases the predicate adjective? Here is an example without a predicate adjective: He ate an enormous amount considering his size.

Comment: I'll do my best to get back to you tomorrow (am dead on my feet right now), but if I forget for some reason please remind me.

Comment: I believe that in this case they modify the clause and would be considered disjuncts by Quirk *et al*. I can't guarantee that though. :)

Comment: I’ve been looking over Quirk (in the prepositions section) and it has cleared up most of my confusion. What you said is the same conclusion I came to, but I still wanted to hear what you thought. The Do So test points out that “sentence modifiers” or disjuncts clearly do not modify only the verb or even just the verb phrase. You can't even really apply the Do So test with these kinds of modifiers. Huddleston doesn’t call them disjuncts, but he does have adjunct categories that match what other’s call disjuncts. And what’s in a name? Thanks for your insights.

Comment: It has occurred to me, however, that H&P recognise two types of Adjunct: Modifiers and Supplements. Modifiers are integrated into the clause or VP, whereas  Supplements hang around unattached to any of the other phrases.